# Flutter Windows build Failed, error LNK1168

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop, flutter-build

While building a Flutter app for Windows in debug mode, this error is occuring. **flutter doctor -v** gives normal output. What might be the cause of this ?

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Windows in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1
LINK : fatal error LNK1168: cannot open F:\{project-name}\build\windows\runner\Debug\{project-name}.exe for writing [F:\{project-name}\build\windows\runner\{project-name}.vcxproj]
Exception: Build process failed.
Exited (sigterm)
```

Comment: I had the same error. A restart of VSCode helped.  

To summarise:
1. Close VSCode 
2. Close related processes (i.e vscode.exe, dart.exe)
3. Start VSCode
4. If above did not help, run `flutter clean`

Comment: It happened again. This time the reason was that the Windows application myapp.exe was still running in the background. After killing the process everything works again.

Answer (score 5):

The issue got resolved after running flutter clean, but i dont know the main cause of this problem

Comment: It's due to the `example.exe` file being utilized somewhere. The OS may have been keeping the process alive for some reason even after you believed you closed it.

Comment: Had the same problem. After hours of research, I figured out it was because.....of my antivirus.

Comment: In my case, the program stuck in background, and everything is fine after I deleted It from task manager.

Comment: I had a different error, namely `LNK 1112`. It also got resolved with `flutter clean`. So I think any LNK errors you get you can just clean project and it works.

Comment: When a program fails with a runtime error, the exe may still be running in the background. So it must be stopped in task manager so that the compiler (vscode) can replace the exe. Also a good idea to stop and start vscode.